# Is there a constant thickness font? (not monospaced)

Tags: font-identification, font-recommendation, font-design

I'm working on 3D printing using FDM (filament) and SLA (resin) technology and I'm always struggling with small text details because I have not found one with a constant thickness path.

Is there a font with a constant or fixed inner path? (I don't know how to call it)

See the red line on the following image as that section is smaller.

[image]

Comment: Yes, stroked fonts are like that. Many CAD apps have those in addition to normal fonts.

Comment: @joojaa thanks a million for pointing me into the right direction! :bow: